# setState not updating react component properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to add *pagination* in React and am sending a query for it, based on the page number of the URL. The data should be fetched and update the same component.

But the problem occurs when I go from page 2 to page 3. The data from page 2 data and page 3 data are shown alternately for a while.

[image]

After some time, the newly fetched data is updated.
I have setPost([]) after page 3 is clicked, but I don't know from where page 2 is coming.

I want to setLoading to true till the newly fetched data is completely fetched.

```
const Daily = ({match}) => {

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [numberOfPages, setNumberOfPages] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const perPageItems = 8;

    useEffect(() => {
        const totalPost = () => {
            getPostsCount()
            .then(data => {
                setNumberOfPages(Math.ceil(data/perPageItems))
            })
        }

        const loadIndexPosts = (a, b) => {
            getPostsByIndex(a, b)
            .then(data => {
                if (data.error) {
                    console.log(data.error);
                } else {
                    setPosts(data);
                }
                setLoading(false);
            })
        };

        totalPost()
        if(match.params.page==undefined)
            match.params.page=1;
         var n = parseInt(match.params.page)-1;
         var startIdx = n*perPageItems;
         loadIndexPosts(startIdx, perPageItems)
    },)

    console.log(posts);

    return (

        <div>
            <div className="mt-5 daily-card-feed">
                {loading && <ThreeDotsWave/>}
                {posts.map((post, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <DailyCard post={post}/>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>


            <div className="h4 pb-5 pull-right mr-5">
                {match.params.page==1 &&
                    <Link to={`/daily/page/2`} onClick={() => {setLoading(true); setPosts([])}}>Older Post -></Link>}
                {match.params.page!=1 &&
                     <Link to={`${parseInt(match.params.page)+1}`} onClick={() => {setLoading(true); setPosts([])}}>Older Post -></Link>}
            </div>

        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: You haven't pass any dependencies to the use effect hook. When do you want to trigger that use effect hook?

Comment: On loading, thanks I added [!loading] in the use effect hook, it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's figure out the logic of loading new data. When a new page arrives at path, you want to call the api. I think the problem is here:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    const totalPost = () => {
        getPostsCount()
        .then(data => {
            setNumberOfPages(Math.ceil(data/perPageItems))
        })
    }

    const loadIndexPosts = (a, b) => {
        getPostsByIndex(a, b)
        .then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                console.log(data.error);
            } else {
                setPosts(data);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        })
    };

    totalPost()
    if(match.params.page==undefined)
        match.params.page=1;
     var n = parseInt(match.params.page)-1;
     var startIdx = n*perPageItems;
     loadIndexPosts(startIdx, perPageItems)
},)
```

We can break this like:

```
const totalPost = () => {
        getPostsCount()
        .then(data => {
            setNumberOfPages(Math.ceil(data/perPageItems))
        })
    }
const loadIndexPosts = (a, b) => {
    getPostsByIndex(a, b)
    .then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
            console.log(data.error);
        } else {
            setPosts(data);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    })
};

useEffect(() => { 
if(match.params.page==undefined)
    match.params.page=1;
 var n = parseInt(match.params.page)-1;
 var startIdx = n*perPageItems;
 loadIndexPosts(startIdx, perPageItems)
},[numberOfPages])
```

This will add the dependency of the call when page number changes. And call **totalPost()** only from click event.

Comment: Yes you are right I need to add the dependency for Use Effect but I added, loading, not numberOfPages. And functions totalPost, loadIndexPosts can be [inside UseEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854902/16341689)